# Delete int[] from ArrayList<int[]>

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to delete an int[] from an ArrayList.
Due to my code I only have the values so I'm creating the array and then call remove();

```
int[] pos = new int[]{0,1};
positionList.remove(pos);
```

positionList is the corrisponding ArrayList

This actually doesn't work. Is there another possibility than iterating through the list like

```
for (int[] pos : positionList) {
  if (posX == pos[0] && posY == pos[1]) {
    positionList.remove(pos);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the `posX` and `posY`, I'm curious if something like `ArrayList<Point>` is a better solution for you.

The reason the `remove` couldn't find the array is because the new array is not `equals` to the array already in the collection.

```
(new int[0]).equals(new int[0]) // false!
```

If you create you own `Point` class, then you can `@Override equals` to behave as you want, and you can simply call `remove(new Point(posX, posY))`.

You should also consider having a `Set<Point> positionList` instead, because implementations offer much faster removal (`O(1)` for `HashSet`, `O(log N)` for `TreeSet`). Remember to `@Override hashCode` (which you have to do anyway if you `@Override equals`), and make `Point implements Comparable<Point>` (or provide an external `Comparator<Point>`) if you want to use `TreeSet` or need to sort the points in other contexts.

If your `int[]` has many elements and a custom `Point` class is not applicable, then you may want to consider switching to `List<Integer>` instead (see also: *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, item 25: prefer lists to arrays). It has the `equals` behavior that you need. It is slower, but it may still be fast enough.

Lastly, if you insist on using `int[]`, you can just wrap it inside your own `IntArray` class, and have a `ArrayList<IntArray>` instead. `@Override equals` and `hashCode` to use  `Arrays.equals(int[], int[])`, and `hashCode(int[])` respectively.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of using HashSet instead of a List.  ArrayList is certainly the most inefficient collection for ad hoc removes.

Comment: Yeah, I try to cover all relevant bases in incremental manner in my answers.

Answer (score 7):

It's a bad practice to use arrays for holding data that isn't a sequence of items, literally.

Your array is actually a data holder with two distinct feilds.
Define a coordinates class and override `Object.equals(Object)`. Then your  code will become much cleaner:

```
ArrayList<MyPoint> positionList;
// fill list
MyPoint testPos = new MyPoint(0, 1);
positionList.remove(testPos);
```

You should be guessing how to define `MyPoint`..

Comment: or better yet, use the actual Point2D or Point class in the JDK, http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html

Comment: Don't forget to override Object#hashCode() too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: There are two issues with Point2D. First it is abstract so Dimitri would need to write a class anyway. Second it uses doubles while Dimitri uses integers..

My general point was using data structures instead of arrays.